Single column foreign key reference multiple columns?
I have a DB where I can't easly modify the structure and logic already in use (since it's a structure replicated in multiple applications) but there are a lot of missing foreign keys that would make my work much easier.

It has two table structured like this:

Pieces:

definitiveCode is unique
internalCode is also unique.
the two sets of possible values are also disjoint



They represent two types of serial number of an item



definitiveCode
internalCode
...




111
222
...


333
444
...




Workings:

pieceCode is the item serial number on witch the working was performed






pieceCode
...




111
...


444
...



I would like to create a constraint that make sure that pieceCode is present in definitiveCode or internalCode to make the insertion of a working safer and, if possible, the removal of a piece easier.
I would expect something like this:
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_working_piece 
FOREIGN KEY (pieceCode)
REFERENCES Pieces(definitiveCode) UNION Pieces(internalCode)

This DB is on SQL Server and I'm in serach for a solution on that but I would like to know if something like that exist for MySQL.

I suspect you're going to, instead, need to use a TRIGGER here; I don't believe you can enforce this with a CONSTRAINT.

Just a sanity check on your design: Your Pieces table to be like a classic "aliases" table relating primary identifiers to alternate identifiers. Often, these allow for one-to-many relationships. Are you sure there can't be more than one definitiveCode per internalCode or vice versa? (For example "Ford premium lug nut", "Mercedes luxury lug nut" "Rolls-Royce super expensive lug nut" all mapping to "Standard stock black lug nut".)

That is simple. You seem to be lacking a piece code table, that's all. The CREATE TABLE statements would look something like this:
CREATE TABLE piececodes
(
  piececode INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (piececode)
);

CREATE TABLE pieces
(
  definitivecode INT,
  internalcode INT,
  CONSTRAINT pieces_unique_definitivecode UNIQUE (definitivecode),   
  CONSTRAINT pieces_unique_internalcode UNIQUE (internalcode),   
  FOREIGN KEY (definitivecode) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode),
  FOREIGN KEY (internalcode) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode)
);

CREATE TABLE workings
(
  piececode INT,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (piececode) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode)
);

If you want to ensure that a piece code can only either be used as a definite code or an internal code, things get a tad complicated. A possible solution with composite keys:
CREATE TABLE piececodetypes
(
  piececodetype VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT piececodetypes_check_type CHECK (piececodetype IN ('DEFINITE', 'INTERNAL')),
  PRIMARY KEY (piececodetype)
);

CREATE TABLE piececodes
(
  piececode INT,
  piececodetype VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (piececode),
  CONSTRAINT piececodes_unique UNIQUE (piececode, piececodetype),
  FOREIGN KEY (piececodetype) REFERENCES piececodetypes (piececodetype)
);

CREATE TABLE pieces
(
  definitivecode INT,
  internalcode INT,
  definitivecodetype  AS CAST('DEFINITE' AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED,
  internalcodetype AS CAST('INTERNAL' AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED,
  CONSTRAINT pieces_unique_definitivecode UNIQUE (definitivecode),   
  CONSTRAINT pieces_unique_internalcode UNIQUE (internalcode),   
  FOREIGN KEY (definitivecode, definitivecodetype) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode, piececodetype),
  FOREIGN KEY (internalcode, internalcodetype) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode, piececodetype)
);

CREATE TABLE workings
(
  piececode INT,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (piececode) REFERENCES piececodes (piececode)
);

